# Progress Dialog not showing up before RXJava call

Tags: android, rx-java, progressdialog

I have the following code, where I start a ring dialog before I make a long running task, done in RxJava2.  The problem is that the dialog isn't showing up and I don't think I'm blocking the main UI thread.

```
  fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ringProgressDialog != null) {
                if (ringProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
            ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SendConversationsActivity.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.creating_document_progress_dialog_title),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.conversation_progress_dialog_text),
                    true, false);
            FileNameAndContacts filenameAndContacts = new FileNameAndContacts();
            if (tvNoDatSelected.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                filenameAndContacts.setFileName("");
            }
            createDocument(filenameAndContacts)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnError(throwable -> Timber.e(throwable, "Error in getting document"))
                    .subscribe(fileAndContacts -> {
                        if (ringProgressDialog.isShowing()) { //debugger says 
                                                              //dialog is showing. 
                            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        sendDocumentInEmail(fileAndContacts);

                    });
     }
```

Task executes properly.  I also show another ring progress dialog before I do another RXJava task in the same activity, this one shows up.

If I comment out the RxJava call, the dialog shows up.  So something in the RxJava call is blocking.

**//EDIT**
This simple observable also blocks the progress dialog from showing (but the Toast displays):

```
                Observable.just("Hello, world")
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                        Toast.makeText(SendConversationsActivity.this, "Toast...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //ringProgressDialog.show();
                    })
                    .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                        //ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    })
                    .subscribe(s -> {
                        //Toast.makeText(SendConversationsActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    });
```

Comment: How is `createDocument` implemented? `create`, `fromCallable`?

Comment: @akarnokd I do the calculations then do a Single.just(fileNameAndContacts).

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is createDocument implemented? create, fromCallable
>
> @akarnokd I do the calculations then do a Single.just(fileNameAndContacts)

As suspected, you compute the document on the current thread (main) and blocking it. You should move it into `fromCallable` and it will compute in the background when combined with `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
     /* compute the document here */
    return fileNameAndContacts;
});
```

Comment: I tried changing my test code to Observable.fromCallable(() -> "Hello World"), and it still did not show the ProgressDialog.  It does, however, show the Toast.

Comment: Maybe it just disappears immediately as the computation is trivial. Apply `delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` after `fromCallable` to give the main thread some time.

Comment: that was it.  The dialog appeared.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest doing RxAndroid2 in this way

```
// Init your dialog
ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
ringProgressDialog.setTitle("Your Title");
ringProgressDialog.setMessage("Your message");

createDocument(filenameAndContacts)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> ringProgressDialog.show())
        .doOnTerminate(() -> {
            if (ringProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .concatMap(fileAndContacts -> sendDocumentInEmail(fileAndContacts))
        .subscribe(this::onSuccess, this::onError)


private void onSuccess() {
    // Do anything you want on Android main thread
}

private void onError() {
    // Timber..
}
```

**Explanation**

The method `doOnSubscribe()` will be called whenever your observable start to subscribe and `doOnTerminate()` will be called just before the resulting `Observable` terminates, whether normally or with an error.

Then, if you want to do another thing like `sendDocumentInEmail` after you get `fileAndContacts`, just use `concatMap()`

So, whenever error happens, you can handle it in `onError()` method.

Doing like this will help you avoid callback hell or side-effect, which easily lead you to error prone.

Reference:

- http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html
- https://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Hope this help

Comment: in RXJava 2 there is no doOnTerminate nor concatMap.  Just FYI.

Comment: doOnTerminate and concatMap has been released in even RxJava1. Did you try it? Ref:http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html

Comment: there is a doAfterTerminate.  RxJava 2 was rewritten from the ground up, it is really different from RxJava 1.

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doOnTerminate(io.reactivex.functions.Action) It still keeping that function. Please check again

Comment: Did you try it, at least one time?

Comment: Yes, and I got compile errors.  I did add the .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> ringProgressDialog) and it did not work.  Here is the updated documentation: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0

Comment: I believe I am using Rxjava2 and RxAndroid2. Try not to use lamda, type the function again. http://imgur.com/a/cPmwY

Comment: Can you check in your build.gradle file to see what version you are using?

Comment: Follow the github of RxAndroid. 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'

Comment: Well, what you gave me won't compile and there is no option for doOnTerminate nor concatmap.

Comment: Well, How about the version, is that right? Is that Rxjav2?

Comment: createDocument returns a Single<FileNameAndContacts>.  Maybe those functions don't work on Singles, but only Observables?

Comment: Ah Ok. Please add this line .toObservable() before doOnSubscribe()

Comment: and this too: sendDocumentInEmail(fileAndContacts).toObservable() if that is a Single

Comment: Where do you add the last line?

Comment: .concatMap(fileAndContacts -> sendDocumentInEmail(fileAndContacts).toObservable())

Comment: That does not compile. sendDocumentInEmail is just a function.

Comment: Ah ok, If that just a method, remove that line, then do it onSucess()

Comment: Please test one by one. First, create new dialog, then test if that could show, then add it with Rx.// Init your dialog
ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
ringProgressDialog.setTitle("Your Title");
ringProgressDialog.setMessage("Your message");ringProgressDialog.show();

Comment: If I comment out the rx call, and just do a ringProgressDialog.show(), the dialog shows.

Comment: Do you have any log? Make sure this line .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) should put before showing dialog

Comment: Yes, .observeOn(AndroidSchedules.mainThread()) is before showing dialog.  No logs...nothing really to show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151430/discussion-between-phat-phat-and-kristy-welsh).